# Scaling according to selected face

Tags: modeling, interface

a complete newbie at blender would very much appreciate some help.

I did something, and now every time I scale a number of faces, they are scaled according to the main selected face, rather than according to the imaginary middle point between all faces.

I need to get it back to normal, and I have no idea how. 
Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Active element is set as pivot point:

[image]

Set it back to "median point".

Comment: Damn, you're fast! :)

Comment: Wow, that was quick! 
Thanks!

Comment: @JachymMichal, it's thanks to Blender's shortcut, "Grasshopper". ; )

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the solution.

In case anyone is anywhere close to being as stupid as me, on the top of the screen, next to snapping and proportional editing, there is a "pivot point" selection. Just change that